# Assign numbers from range to letters based on their position in a string

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code which should evenly assign the numbers 0-255 to the letters in a string. the first lettter should be 0 and the last should be 255. However, with my code (most likely due to rounding the number somewhere) I get lower numbers like 252 as maximum. This is my code:

```
string x = "abcde";
(255 / (x.Length - 1)) * x.IndexOf("e")
```

This should give 255

Comment: No, it should give 255 / 16.

Comment: Integer division always truncates the  fractional part, this gives the expected result because it uses a double: `(255.0 / (x.Length - 1)) * x.IndexOf("e")`

Comment: @EricTrigo: why 255 / 16??

Comment: `255 * x.IndexOf("e") / (x.Length - 1)`

Comment: @EricTrigo: no, because of parenthesis, we have 255 / 4 first, then multiplied by 4.

Comment: @Slyvain: even without parentheses left to right evaluation of operators with equal precedence would still have the same result - to get 255 / 16 the parentheses would need to be _255 / ((x.Length - 1) * x.IndexOf("e"))_

Comment: @PaulF: Thank you for the precision. So, in OP's post, the parenthesis around `255 / (x.Lenght - 1)` are useless, correct?

Comment: @Slyvain: they have no effect on the result - but readability is improved (at least as far as I am concerned - obviously not Eric).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`255 / (x.Length - 1)` is an Integer-operation, thus you get `255 / 4` which is `63` instead of `63,75`.

You need to tell the compiler you want some floating-point-handling by appending either `f`to your first number or `.0`:

```
255.0 / (x.Length - 1)
```

or

```
255f / (x.Length - 1)
```

Comment: You're missing parentheses, should be `255f / (x.Length - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you need to cast one thing to `double` like this:

```
(int)((255 / (double)(x.Length - 1)) * x.IndexOf("e"))
```

or

```
(int)((255d / (x.Length - 1)) * x.IndexOf("e"))
```

or

```
(int)((255.0 / (x.Length - 1)) * x.IndexOf("e"))
```

Test: https://ideone.com/ePyo8J

Answer (score 0):

LINQ

```
static IEnumerable<int> WordToIntList(string s)
{
    return s.ToCharArray().ToList().Select((c, i) => (int) (255.0*(i))/(s.Length - 1));
}
```